# Windows Task Scheduler Not Running Microsoft Access Script

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks, microsoft-access, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

I have a script setup in an Access database that I want to run nightly. I've setup a task in task scheduler to run every day at 4:00am. It opens the database, runs the script, and the last line of the VBA script closes the database.

The tasks will work fine for a few days, and then I'll see that it stops working. I have the task set to stop after 2 hours (which is way more than enough time). I'm assuming what is happening is that when the database opens, a security popup is preventing the script from running.

I've set the database file as trusted and when I open it manually, it seems fine.

Below is what I have as the action for the task:

Program/Script: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office15\MSACCESS.EXE"

Add arguments: "\path to database\database.accdb" /x MacroName"

The task is running everyday, so I believe the task in task scheduler is setup correctly. I'm just not sure why the script in Access isn't running, again, my guess is that a popup is occuring when the database opens, preventing the script from running (Even though I've set the location as a trusted location).

Any help/tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I would try the following

#1

instead of passing the /x MacroName on the command line,

you could run code inside your specified database Startup form OnOpen event.

e.g.  if the current time is between 3am and 5am then run MacroName

#2   Check the quote marks in your command line (your arguments listed above has three double quotes... you should have an even-number of double quotes in your command line, not odd number

#3  Create a table for logging messages, with a date/timestamp field

Inside your 4am code
sprinkle some lines of code to add rows into this Log table.
Inspect the log table later to see how far throughout your Macro the code is actually getting to... it could be one particular piece of your code is crashing occasionally?

#4   If it is still stopping every day then change the time to when you are on your computer and can observe the behavior for a week or so, and if your suspicion is correct, you will see the popup occur

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions! Unfortunately, I've still been running into the same issues and I'm thinking its caused by the security popup that disables VBA until you enable it. I've posted another question regarding the issue [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1649499/updating-access-tables-from-vbscript-using-task-scheduler).

Answer (score 0):

@Thetafinity have you found the solution for your problem, it seems I am having the same as you and have no idea how to solve it. Would appreciate if you could share solution.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1131106)